# Middleware For Users Roles and Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I'm wanting to develop some middleware for my Laravel 5 application. I have some criteria for this middleware that I need help thinking about and trying to help understand what could possibly be the best route to handle this tasks.

I have multiple users. And each user has ONE role. Each role has permissions on what they are allowed to do AND I would like to have a way for user's to be able to override their roles permissions and have their specific permissions to them.

This way if I have John Doe who is a Basic User and normal basic users aren't allowed to create an article but I can make it to where in the database that John Doe can then I want to be able to to allow for that.

I hope that is as much information as I needed to provide minus my current database schema which I'm about to provide.

```
Table: users
Fields: id, username, email, role_id

Table: roles
Fields: id, role, description

Table: permissions
Fields: id, permission, description

Table: permission_role
Fields: id, permission_id, role_id
```

Comment: Try using package that is tailored for this task, Zizacos Entrust, Sentry... Just go to packalyst and search.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend you to evaluate Zizaco's [Enstrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) L5 package. If you need something else or you want to code yourself this, then review the package code for guiadance.

Comment: Can you explain the advantage/disadvantage of doing something like Entrust vs. doing something that is middleware related?

Comment: You can use Entrust in your middleware to check roles, permissions or hability before or after a request is made, look at [middleware laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware)

Comment: Advantage is that the package is very mature and well supported by the community, implements your case, and is ready to use. I think Entrust is middleware related in the context above explained (Can be used in middleware)

Comment: @OmeCoatl Does Entrust support Role-Permission-Context that is a given role has some given permission on a certain context

Comment: @DucCuong, to my knowledge, entrust doesnt support it, but i think you could use filters (or middleware in L5) with entrust to achieve the same concept.

Comment: @OmeCoatl I agree. That is also the solution I was thinking about.